# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( error in Javascript

Tags: javascript

What's wrong with below code? Why I got an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`

```
function Person(name){
    sayHi: function(){
      return "hi " + this.name;
    }
}

var john = new Person("John");
alert(john.sayhi());
```

Comment: The first '{' starts a function, not an object literal..

Comment: function Person(name){
    return {sayHi: function(){
      return "hi " + this.name;
    }}
}

Comment: @user2864740 how to make it into an object?

Comment: Besides what @DanielTate said, you are calling 'sayhi' but you defined it as 'sayHi'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that declaration of sayHi is invalid because you are not in the same context as an object literal, so you are having a syntax error.

```
var o = { sayHi: function() {}} ;
```

you could do it using "this" (Because you are using "new" already) :

```
function Person(name){

    this.sayHi = function(){
        return "hi " + name;
    }
}

var john = new Person("John");
alert(john.sayHi());
```

another way is

```
function Person(name){

   return {
      sayHi : function() {
         return "hi " + name;
      }
   }
}    

var john = Person("John");
alert(john.sayHi());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `this` to make the variables and functions public of a class. If you dont use `this` keyword with variables then they can only accessible inside the class.

Please check this code.

```
function Person(name){
  this.sayHi = function(){
    return "hi " + name;
  }
}
var john = new Person("John");
alert(john.sayHi());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change like this:

```
function Person(name){
    this.sayHi = function(){
      return "hi " + name;
    }
}

var john = new Person("John");
alert(john.sayHi());
```

Or something like this

```
function Person(name){
    this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.sayHi = function(){
      return "hi " + this.name;
}
var john = new Person("John");
alert(john.sayHi());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an Object Constructor:

```js
function Person(name){
    this._name = name;
    this.sayHi = function(){
      return "hi " + this._name;
    }
}

var john = new Person("John");
alert(john.sayHi());
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please check this code

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.sayHi = function(name) {

      return name;
   }; 
})( jQuery );

alert($('body').sayHi('dasd'));
```

Answer (score 0):

For additional clarity you can take the sayhi method out of the Person Object declaration as below.

Declare Person Object, including name and sayhi function.

```
function Person(nameString){
        this.name = nameString;
        this.message = sayhi;
    }
```

State what sayhi should do.

```
function sayhi(){
    return hiString = "hi " + this.name;
}
```

Initiate your Person

```
var john = new Person("John");
```

Call sayhi function on your Person Object and alert the return value

```
alert(john.sayhi());
```